# Bomberman: What container to use to draw elements in a certain order (z-coordinate)?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, sfml

In my SFML bomberman clone I have a tilemap that consists of tiles.

Tiles can overlap, so  those tiles that are farther down will be drawn over those tiles farther up. The same goes for all other entities like the player.

---

In order to draw all entities in the correct order, I thought about giving each entity some sort of z-coordinate (entities whose z-coord is lower will be drawn first).

My plan was to have one vector with ALL entities (tiles, player, bombs, power-ups, etc.) and whenever an element is added, the vector's elements are sorted from lowest to highest z-coord so they are drawn in the correct order.

---

My idea was to assign the following z-coords to the entities:

```
0: tiles in the 1st row
2: tiles in the 2nd row
4: tiles in the 3rd row
etc.
```

Entities that are for example on the 1st row of tiles will have a coord of 1. Those on the 2nd row will have a coord of 3, etc.

---

Does using a std::vector make sense for this? Maybe a list, or a map (z would be the key)? I'm struggling to find the best and easiest-to-use container for this.

I know this post lacks code, but I'm really lost and would be so grateful if someone could give me some hints.

Comment: Why involve a Z-coordinate at all? Why not keep the items to draw sorted in Y-coordinate order, so items with higher Y coordinate value (if the top is zero) will automatically be drawn over the items with lower Y coordinates? It *is* a 2D game after all, isn't it? :)

Comment: What you need is an index, not a container.

Comment: True... so I'll just sort the vector by the y-coords? I'll try that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need vector for static tiles.

You can just create a normal 2D array of tiles.

It's faster and you don't need to use Z-buffer:
Instead, you should just write `for` loop in a such way that tiles are rendered from top to bottom.